# show fpdf data in html

Tags: php, fpdf

We are trying to get all html data of fpdf but it's showing like this

```
���QO�0�����
```

we are using this piece of code to show html data

```
print_r($pdf->output("test.pdf", 'S'));
```

explanation

we are setting data like this

```
 $pdf->Cell(30,8,"$res1->pro_type2",1,0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,8,"$res1->sub_type2",1,0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,8,"$res1->bedrooms",1,0);
 $pdf->Cell(20,8,"$res1->bathroom",1,0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,8,"$res1->carpet $res1->blank2",1,0);
 $pdf->Cell(20,8,"$res1->price",1,0);
 $pdf->Cell(30,8,"$res1->tower",1,1);
```

this created the pdf with data, But we want html output as it's showing in pdf.

Please tell us how can we get html data of fpdf?

Comment: What do you mean by html data of fpdf?

Want to load pdf in a div?

Comment: I modified my question. Please check.

Comment: It can be accomplished with js or jquery. Just provide your html structure

Comment: actually pdf is generated using all fpdf tags. Like in given example.  So how can we get using JS?

Comment: Load the pdf in an iframe and  and access iframe window contents with js

Comment: Are you sure? Is this possible?

Comment: Share your pdf and let me attempt

Comment: OK. here is my file 
http://www.filedropper.com/doc_6